# JodaTime Formatter confusion

Tags: java, datetime, date, jodatime

When I retrieve a date from a string e.g. "Sat 11 Feb" using Jodatime formatting classes:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EE dd MMM");
```

I get back a date (after parsing) of: "Saturday, 12 February 00:00"

Can anyone explain this? I would expect a DateMidnight for the 11th not the 12th.

This is the code I am using:

```
private static String STYLE = "EE dd MMM";
private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(STYLE);
public static DateTime getDate(String str) {
return formatter.parseDateTime(str);
}

String dateExample = "Sat 11 Feb";
log.info(dateExample);
DateTime eventDate = getDate(dateExample);
log.info(eventDate.toString());
```

And this is what is logged:

2012-02-09_11:12:40.592 INFO   - Sat 11 Feb

2012-02-09_11:12:40.664 INFO   - 2000-02-12T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: Can you show the actual code that you use to parse the string and show that the resulting date object has the wrong value?

Comment: Please provide all the relevant code. All you have given is the code for constructing the `formatter`. How are you using the formatter to parse the text? And then once you have the parsed result, how are you determining that it is 12th Feb, rather than 11th Feb (toString? Formatter?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11 Feb 2000 was a Friday, not a Saturday.

Comment: Thanks, completely missed the year! I assumed it would be the current year.